# Errors on [indexPath!] and [newIndexPath!] - the message "Cannot convert value of type 'NSIndexPath?' to expected element type 'IndexPath'

Tags: controller, nsarray, nsindexpath

```
// Errors on [indexPath!] and [newIndexPath!] ---- the message "Cannot convert value of type 'NSIndexPath?' to expected element type 'Array<IndexPath>.ArrayLiteralElement' (aka 'IndexPath')" 

func controller(controller:   
    NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChangeObject
    anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, 
    forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: 
                                                      NSIndexPath?) {

    switch(type) {
      case .insert:
          self.heroTableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!],  
                                            withRowAnimation: .fade)
      case .delete:
          self.heroTableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!],     
                                            withRowAnimation: .fade) 
      default:
          ()
   }
}
```

Comment: What version of Xcode and iOS SDK are you using? Your code seems outdated.

Comment: I am under Xcode 14 and iOS 16. 
Please let me know how to fix it.

Comment: Your code is outdated and needs an update. See the documentation of `insertRowsAtIndexPaths`.

Comment: I will try this and let you know the result.

Comment: There is "- (void)insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray<NSIndexPath *> *)indexPaths 
              withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;" but I have no idea how to use this. Could you please let me know how to use this?

Comment: Swich language to Swift (upper right). The Swift version is now `insertRows(at:with:)`.

Comment: I have changed it to "self.heroTableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath!], with: .fade)", but there is the same error on it.

Comment: Did you change `NSIndexPath` to `IndexPath`?

Comment: I didn't change the func controller's parameters. indexPath: NSIndexPath?, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath? in func controller.

Comment: After I have changed these two parameters to indexPath: IndexPath?, newIndexPath: IndexPath?, the error messages have gone. Thank you, Willeke.

Comment: Thank you, Willeke. I have posted this for those who will meet the same error. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, Willeke. I have another problem. After build and run, on "let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Hero", inManagedObjectContext: context!)" Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. I replaced it to "let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Hero", in: context!)" but there is the same error message.

Comment: Good evening, Willeke. Could you please take a look my another question that I posted ?

Comment: Hi, Willeke. Could  you please take a look my another posting  regarding constant ‘entity’ and ‘context!’?

Answer (score 1):

// Thank you, Willeke.
// I post this for those who will meet the same errors.

```
func controller(controller:   
    NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChangeObject
    anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath?, 
    forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: 
                                                      IndexPath?) {

    switch(type) {
      case .insert:
          self.heroTableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath!], with: .fade)
                                                            
      case .delete:
          self.heroTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .fade)    
                                                          
      default:
          ()
   }
}
```